# How can i create a branch in svn using SharpSVN

Tags: .net, sharpsvn

I am using SharpSVN to access my subversion repository using SharpSVN, i need a means to create a branch programatically using SharpSVN, how is this done!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually a branch is created with `svn copy <path> <URL>` or `svn copy <URL1> <URL2>`.

With SharpSvn you can perform this operation using `SvnClient.RemoteCopy()`. The function `SvnClient.Copy()` is only used when the target is a local path.